# Multiple renderer in esri map

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have requirement which is using classbreakrenderer for showing clusters size as it breaks down, now i want to use one renderer which shows different different symbol for single cluster based on some attribute value.

I have tried to use UniqueValueRenderer but it not working.

Any suggestion
I have requirement which is using classbreakrenderer for showing clusters size as it breaks down, now i want to use one renderer which shows different different symbol for single cluster based on some attribute value.

I have tried to use UniqueValueRenderer but it not working.
I have requirement which is using classbreakrenderer for showing clusters size as it breaks down, now i want to use one renderer which shows different different symbol for single cluster based on some attribute value.

I have tried to use UniqueValueRenderer but it not working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            packages: [
            {
                name: 'app',
                location: window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/src'
            }
        ]};
    </script>

    <!-- ArcGIS API for JavaScript library references -->
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15compact"></script>
    <script>
    require(["esri/map",
        "esri/dijit/Geocoder",
        "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "esri/graphic",
        "esri/graphicsUtils",
        "app/clusterfeaturelayer",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
        "esri/renderers/HeatmapRenderer",
        "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
        "dojo/_base/Color",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom-style",
        "dojo/_base/fx",
        "dojo/fx/easing",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
      function (Map, Geocoder, HomeButton, SimpleRenderer, PictureMarkerSymbol, FeatureLayer, UniqueValueRenderer, InfoTemplate, Graphic, graphicsUtils, ClusterFeatureLayer, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, PictureMarkerSymbol, ClassBreaksRenderer, HeatmapRenderer, Color, on, domStyle, fx, easing, dom) {

        // Locals
        var map,
            popup,
            clusterLayer,
            geocoder,
            infoTemplate,
            defaultSym,
            selectedSym,
            activeClusterElement;

        // Create map
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
            basemap: "dark-gray",
            center: [-120, 50],
            zoom: 3
        });

        // Create widget
        geocoder = new Geocoder({
            value: "California, United States",
            autoNavigate: true,
            maxLocations: 25,
            autoComplete: true,
            arcgisGeocoder: {
            outFields: "Place_addr, PlaceName, Score"
            },
            map: map
            }, "search");
        geocoder.startup();

        var home = new HomeButton({
            map: map
        }, "homeButton");
        home.startup();

        // Add raw points
        // var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/oKgs2tbjK6zwTdvi/arcgis/rest/services/Major_World_Cities/FeatureServer/0", {
        //         infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
        //         outFields: ["*"]
        //     });
        // map.addLayer(featureLayer);

        // Add heatmap
        // var featureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/oKgs2tbjK6zwTdvi/arcgis/rest/services/Major_World_Cities/FeatureServer/0");
        // var heatmapRenderer = new HeatmapRenderer();
        // featureLayer2.setRenderer(heatmapRenderer);
        // map.addLayer(featureLayer2);

        // Add clusters 
        map.on("load", function () {
            // Add layer
            addClusterLayer();
            addClusterLayerEvents();
        });

        // Set popup
        popup = map.infoWindow;
        popup.highlight = false;
        popup.titleInBody = false;
        popup.domNode.className += " light";
        //popup.domNode.style.marginTop = "-17px";  // for pins only

        // Popup content
        //infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Seismic Activity > 4.0", "<p>Location: ${NAME}</p><p>Magnitude: ${OTHER_MAG1}</p><p>Date: ${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</p>");

        infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("<b>${CITY_NAME}</b>", "<p>COUNTRY: ${CNTRY_NAME}</p><p>STATE/PROVINCE: ${ADMIN_NAME}</p><p>POPULATION: ${POP}</p>");


        // Option 1: Esri marker for single locations and selections        
        // defaultSym = new createPictureSymbol("./images/blue-cluster-pin.png", 0, 8, 9, 16);
        // selectedSym = new createPictureSymbol("./images/blue-cluster-pin.png", 0, 9, 11, 20);

        // Option 2: Use circle markers for symbols - Red
        defaultSym = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 16,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([102,0,0, 0.55]), 3),
                        new Color([255, 255, 255, 1]));

        selectedSym = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 16,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([102,0,0, 0.85]), 3),
                        new Color([255, 255, 255, 1]));

        // Create a feature layer to get feature service
        function addClusterLayer() {
            var renderer,
                renderer1,
                small,
                medium,
                large,
                xlarge;

            // Add cluster renderer
            clusterLayer = new ClusterFeatureLayer({
                "url": "http://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/World_Cities/FeatureServer/0",
                //"url": "http://services.arcgis.com/BG6nSlhZSAWtExvp/arcgis/rest/services/GlobalSeismographyNetwork/FeatureServer/0",
                // "url": "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Earthquakes/Since_1970/MapServer/0",
                "distance": 95,
                "id": "clusters",
                "labelColor": "#fff",
                "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
                //"singleColor": "#888",
                "singleSymbol": defaultSym,
                "singleTemplate": infoTemplate,
                "useDefaultSymbol": false,
                "zoomOnClick": false,
                "showSingles": true,
                "objectIdField": "FID",
                outFields: ["*"]
            });

            renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(defaultSym, "clusterCount");

            // Red Clusters
            small = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 25,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([212,116,60,0.5]), 15),
                        new Color([212,116,60,0.75]));
            medium = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 50,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([178,70,37,0.5]), 15),
                        new Color([178,70,37,0.75]));
            large = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 80,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([144,24,13,0.5]), 15),
                        new Color([144,24,13,0.75]));
            xlarge = new SimpleMarkerSymbol("circle", 110,
                        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([102,0,0,0.5]), 15),
                        new Color([102,0,0,0.75]));

            // Break values - can adjust easily
            renderer.addBreak(2, 50, small);
            renderer.addBreak(50, 250, medium);
            renderer.addBreak(250, 1000, large);
            renderer.addBreak(1000, 50000, xlarge);

            // Providing a ClassBreakRenderer is also optional
            clusterLayer.setRenderer(renderer);

            //added second renderer
            var renderer1 = new UniqueValueRenderer(defaultSymbol, "CNTRY_NAME");

          //add symbol for each possible value

         renderer1.addValue("United States", new PictureMarkerSymbol({
             "angle": 0,
             "xoffset": 0,
             "yoffset": 8,
             "type": "esriPMS",
             "url": "./images/blue-pin.png",
             "contentType": "image/png",
             "width": 24,
             "height": 24
             }));
         renderer1.addValue("Argentina", new PictureMarkerSymbol({
             "angle": 0,
             "xoffset": 0,
             "yoffset": 12,
             "type": "esriPMS",
             "url": "./images/blue-cluster-pin.png",
             "contentType": "image/png",
             "width": 24,
             "height": 24
             }));
        //added to cluster
        clusterLayer.setRenderer(renderer1);

            map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
        }

        // Create png marker
        // function createPictureSymbol(url, xOffset, yOffset, xWidth, yHeight) {
        //     return new PictureMarkerSymbol(
        //         {
        //             "angle": 0,
        //             "xoffset": xOffset,
        //             "yoffset": yOffset,
        //             "type": "esriPMS",
        //             "url": url,
        //             "contentType": "image/png",
        //             "width": xWidth,
        //             "height": yHeight
        //         }
        //     );
        // }

        // Create new graphic and add to map.graphics
        function addSelectedFeature() {
            var selIndex = map.infoWindow.selectedIndex,
                selFeature;
            if (selIndex !== -1) {
                selFeature = map.infoWindow.features[selIndex];
                // Remove old feature first
                removeSelectedFeature();
                // Add new graphic
                map.infoWindow._lastSelected = new Graphic(selFeature.toJson());
                map.infoWindow._lastSelected.setSymbol(selectedSym);
                map.graphics.add(map.infoWindow._lastSelected);
            }
        }

        // Remove graphic from map.graphics
        function removeSelectedFeature() {
            if (map.infoWindow._lastSelected) {
                map.graphics.remove(map.infoWindow._lastSelected);
                map.infoWindow._lastSelected = null;
            }
        }

        // Highlight clusters
        function setActiveClusterOpacity(elem, fillOpacity, strokeOpacity) {
            var textElm;
            if (elem) {
                elem.setAttribute("fill-opacity", fillOpacity);
                elem.setAttribute("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity);
                // Overide inherited properties for the text in the circle
                textElm = elem.nextElementSibling;
                if (textElm && textElm.nodeName === "text") {
                    textElm.setAttribute("fill-opacity", 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // Hide popup if selected feature is clustered
        function onClustersShown(clusters) {
            var  i = 0,
                extent;
            if (map.infoWindow.isShowing && map.infoWindow._lastSelected) {
                for (i; i < clusters.length; i++) {
                    if (clusters[i].attributes.clusterCount > 1) {
                        extent = clusterLayer._getClusterExtent(clusters[i]);
                        if (extent.contains(map.infoWindow._lastSelected.geometry)) {
                            map.infoWindow.hide();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Wire cluster layer events
        function addClusterLayerEvents() {
            // Mouse over events
            clusterLayer.on("mouse-over", onMouseOverCluster);
            clusterLayer.on("mouse-out", onMouseOutCluster);
            // Clusters drawn
            clusterLayer.on("clusters-shown", onClustersShown);
        }

        // Save the last selected graphic so we can highlight it
        map.infoWindow.on("selection-change", function () {
            addSelectedFeature();
            animateInfoWindow();
        });

        // Clear selected graphic when infoWindow is hidden
        map.infoWindow.on("hide", function () {
            // re-activate cluster
            setActiveClusterOpacity(activeClusterElement, 0.75, 0.5);
            removeSelectedFeature();
        });

        // Popup enhancements
        function onMouseOverCluster(e) {
            if (e.graphic.attributes.clusterCount === 1) {
                e.graphic._graphicsLayer.onClick(e);
            } else {
                if (e.target.nodeName === "circle") {
                    activeClusterElement = e.target;
                    setActiveClusterOpacity(activeClusterElement, 1, 1);
                } else {
                    setActiveClusterOpacity(activeClusterElement, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        function onMouseOutCluster(e) {
            if (e.graphic.attributes.clusterCount > 1) {
                if (e.target.nodeName === "circle" || e.target.nodeName === "text") {
                    setActiveClusterOpacity(activeClusterElement, 0.75, 0.5);
                    setActiveClusterOpacity(e.target, 0.75, 0.5);
                }
            }
        }

        function animateInfoWindow() {
            domStyle.set(map.infoWindow.domNode, "opacity", 0);
            fx.fadeIn({node: map.infoWindow.domNode,
                duration: 150,
                easing: easing.quadIn}).play();
        }

        // Click to close
        map.on('click', function () {
            if (map.infoWindow.isShowing) {
                map.infoWindow.hide();
            }
        });

        // ESC is pressed
        map.on('key-down', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                map.infoWindow.hide();
            }
        });

        // Dynamically reposition popups when map moves
        map.on('extent-change', function () {
            if (map.infoWindow.isShowing) {
                map.infoWindow.reposition();
            }
        });

        // Auto recenter map - optional
        autoRecenter(map);

        function autoRecenter(map) {
          on(map, 'load', function (map) {
            on(window, 'resize', map, map.resize);
          });
          on(map, 'resize',  function(extent, width, height) { 
            map.__resizeCenter = map.extent.getCenter();
            setTimeout(function() {
                map.centerAt(map.__resizeCenter);
            }, 100);
          });
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    <div id="search"></div>
    <div id="homeButton"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code and explain what do you mean with "not working"?.

Comment: added code, after adding multiple renderer, no rendereris working